# Black objects in cycles render

Tags: rendering

I rendered a scene and an object was visible. Then I changed material's surface(maybe I accidentally changed something else) and an object became black. It's still fine in rendered viewport shading!

[image]

Comment: So it renders normally in the viewport, but then it is solid black in the final render?

Comment: yep. I guess so

Comment: Any chance you set something unwanted in the renderlayer's mask layers?

Comment: OMG. the problem in massk layer indeed. ty

Comment: @Polosson Go ahead and post as answer so OP can accept it, get this off of the unanswered list . . .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may have unintentionally modified the **mask layers** of the **Renderlayers** tab, in properties panel :

[image]